# Passing extent from web map to PDF for integration?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, pdf, extents

I'm trying to figure out whether I can take an extent (or coordinatess with a Zoom level included) to a PDF in order to author a PDF that displays both GIS and report-styled business data?

Is this something possible with ArcGIS API for JavaScript or even via Flex?

Answer (score 1):

yes.

the extent of a map is accessible via map.[extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#extent).  the zoom level is accessible via map.[getLevel()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#getlevel)

Comment: I understand that the extent and zoom are accessible via Javascript. I guess I should have worded the question differently. I will now edit.

Comment: Nevermind. You answered the question as I asked it. Thank you. I will need to start a new question as I didn't phrase this even remotely close to what I was trying to ask...